# How do I say "add next item", instead of displaying or repeating the fields for each item over again?

Tags: html

Here is the HTML I have thusly:

```html
<form class="form-horizontal row-fluid" id='form1'>

  <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="basicinput">Select Item</label>
    <div class="controls">
      <select tabindex="1" data-placeholder="Select here.." class="span8" id="item_name">
        <option value="">Select Product</option>
        <option value="Category 1">Botts</option>
        <option value="Category 2">Bags</option>
        <option value="Category 3">Table</option>
        <option value="Category 4">Tape</option>
        <option value="Category 4">Frame</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="basicinput">Item Price</label>
    <div class="controls">
      <div class="input-append">
        <input type="text" placeholder="00.000" class="span8" id="item_price"><span class="add-on">R</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="basicinput">Item quantity</label>
    <div class="controls">
      <div class="input-append">
        <input type="text" placeholder="00.000" class="span8" id="item_quantity" onblur='Calculate();'>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="basicinput">Total Due</label>
    <div class="controls">
      <div class="input-append">
        <input type="text" placeholder="00.000" class="span8" id="total_due" disabled><span class="add-on">R</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <hr>


  <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="basicinput">Select Item</label>
    <div class="controls">
      <select tabindex="1" data-placeholder="Select here.." class="span8" id="item_name2">
        <option value="">Select Product</option>
        <option value="Category 1">Botts</option>
        <option value="Category 2">Bags</option>
        <option value="Category 3">Table</option>
        <option value="Category 4">Tape</option>
        <option value="Category 4">Frame</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="basicinput">Item Price</label>
    <div class="controls">
      <div class="input-append">
        <input type="text" placeholder="00.000" class="span8" id="item_price2"><span class="add-on">R</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="basicinput">Item quantity</label>
    <div class="controls">
      <div class="input-append">
        <input type="text" placeholder="00.000" class="span8" id="item_quantity2" onblur='Calculate2();'>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="basicinput">Total Due</label>
    <div class="controls">
      <div class="input-append">
        <input type="text" placeholder="00.000" class="span8" id="total_due2" disabled><span class="add-on">R</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <hr>

  <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="basicinput">Select Item</label>
    <div class="controls">
      <select tabindex="1" data-placeholder="Select here.." class="span8" id="item_name3">
        <option value="">Select Product</option>
        <option value="Category 1">Botts</option>
        <option value="Category 2">Bags</option>
        <option value="Category 3">Table</option>
        <option value="Category 4">Tape</option>
        <option value="Category 4">Frame</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="basicinput">Item Price</label>
    <div class="controls">
      <div class="input-append">
        <input type="text" placeholder="00.000" class="span8" id="item_price3"><span class="add-on">R</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="basicinput">Item quantity</label>
    <div class="controls">
      <div class="input-append">
        <input type="text" placeholder="00.000" class="span8" id="item_quantity3" onblur='Calculate3();'>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="basicinput">Total Due</label>
    <div class="controls">
      <div class="input-append">
        <input type="text" placeholder="00.000" class="span8" id="total_due3" disabled><span class="add-on">R</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <hr>

  <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="basicinput">Select Item</label>
    <div class="controls">
      <select tabindex="1" data-placeholder="Select here.." class="span8" id="item_name4">
        <option value="">Select Product</option>
        <option value="Category 1">Botts</option>
        <option value="Category 2">Bags</option>
        <option value="Category 3">Table</option>
        <option value="Category 4">Tape</option>
        <option value="Category 4">Frame</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="basicinput">Item Price</label>
    <div class="controls">
      <div class="input-append">
        <input type="text" placeholder="00.000" class="span8" id="item_price4"><span class="add-on">R</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="basicinput">Item quantity</label>
    <div class="controls">
      <div class="input-append">
        <input type="text" placeholder="00.000" class="span8" id="item_quantity4" onblur='Calculate4();'>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="basicinput">Total Due</label>
    <div class="controls">
      <div class="input-append">
        <input type="text" placeholder="00.000" class="span8" id="total_due4" disabled><span class="add-on">R</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

To start off, it should be noted that there is no way to do this with just HTML without copy/pasting over and over again. You'll have to add some kind of scripting language either server or client side. For beginners, I would recommend JavaScript since it's the simplest to use and works out of the box.

I'm used to working with jQuery but here is something I patched together from basic JavaScript. The idea is, clicking on the "Add More" link copies your html over and over again with each click and appends it to a new `<div>` element. I put the html you want to copy in its own `<div>` so I can clone/copy the elements inside of that `<div>` only.

Please note the code I created took me about 5 minutes to create, so you'll have to perfect it but it should be enough to get you started.

https://jsfiddle.net/vp56otvt/2/

Here is some of the key JavaScript code I used to make this work:

```
document.getElementById("add").addEventListener("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var itm = document.getElementById("original-form");
    var cln = itm.cloneNode(true);
    document.getElementById("add-more").appendChild(document.createElement("hr"));
    document.getElementById("add-more").appendChild(cln);
});
```

Comment: Many Thanks Err this helps a lot.

Comment: If this answer helped you and you think it sufficiently answered your question, you can accept my answer by clicking on the check mark on the top left-hand side of this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, I do something like below (requires some JavaScript).

[image: Before]
results in:

[image: After]

Here's what that might look like using jQuery *(a popular JS framework)*:

```
    $("table a.addLine").click(function() {
            id++;
            var master = $(this).closest("table");

            // Get a new row based on the prototype row
            var prot = master.find(".prototype").clone();

            // make some changes to the clone
            prot.removeClass("prototype");
            prot.find("input, select").removeAttr("disabled");

            // attach it below the existing ones on the page
            master.find("tbody").append(prot);

            // this is specific to my code, it adds an 'onchange' handler
            // to the select (to fetch item pricing & availability) -- see note
            applyChange();
            return false;
    });
```

And the HTML *(you can ignore the templating directives)*:

```
<table border="0" id="details" style="margin-top: 3px">
    ...
<td class="smallCentered">(<a class="addLine" href="#">add a line</a>)</td>
    ...
<tr class="prototype">
<th></th>
<td>
${include cat-items 'disabled="disabled" class="itemSelect"'}
</td>
<td>\
<input class="itemQuantity" ${NO} name="quantity" size="3" maxlength="7"></td>
<td>@</td>
<td>$<input class="itemUnitCost" ${NO} ${RO} size="5" maxlength="5"></td>
<td>=</td>
<td>$<input class="itemExtended" ${NO} ${RO} size="7" maxlength="7"></td>
<td class="small">&nbsp;(<a class="removeLine" href="#">remove this line</a>)</td>
</tr>
```

And the CSS:

```
.prototype    { display: none; }
```

Comment: That looks similar to what im trying to produce, but im very new at coding i just started learning JavaScript and have not got around to learning the frameworks.

Comment: Here is an intro to JavaScript: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/A_re-introduction_to_JavaScript / Frameworks can engender strong partisanship.  I like jQuery.  Here is a quick intro to it https://www.slideshare.net/mobile/matthewbuchanan/zero-to-hero-a-jquery-primer (one of many, I'm sure)

Comment: Regardless of framework or not, the basic idea is that you take an existing structure on the page, "clone" it, and then attach it below the last one on the page.  I choose to use a hidden and disabled "prototype" structure, but you could simply start with one structure on the page and use it.

Comment: Note: I wrote this code when jQuery was at version 1.3.  Starting with jQuery 1.4 you can say `.clone(true)` and it will include event handlers (and `.data()`) in the cloning operation.  So, if I wrote this today, I could have the "onchange" event handler on the prototype and not need to add it in my `applyChange` function.  More on jQuery's `.clone()` function here: https://api.jquery.com/clone/